# Coin change with limited coins

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys

def minCoins(coins, m, how, V):
    # table[i] will be storing the minimum  
    # number of coins required for i value.  
    # So table[V] will have result 
    table = [0 for i in range(V + 1)] 
    index = []
    # Base case (If given value V is 0) 
    table[0] = 0

    # Initialize all table values as Infinite 
    for i in range(1, V + 1): 
        table[i] = sys.maxsize 

    # Compute minimum coins required  
    # for all values from 1 to V 
    for i in range(1, V + 1):
        # Go through all coins smaller than i 
        for j in range(m): 
            if (coins[j] <= i): 
                sub_res = table[i - coins[j]]
                if (sub_res != sys.maxsize and 
                    sub_res + 1 < table[i]):
                    if sub_res +1 <= how[j] :
                        table[i] = sub_res + 1

    return table[V]

coins = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
howmanycoins = [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 8]
m = len(coins)
V = 16
print("Minimum coins required is ", minCoins(coins, m, howmanycoins, V))
```

I have problem with this code.
When table `howmanycoins` has this values `[0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 7, 9]` program give good answer 7x "2" + 2x "1" = 9 coins, but when 8 is in the last place the output looks like this:

> Minimum coins required is  9223372036854775807.

Comment: Please review the indentation of your code. It is currently not correct (e.g. function minCoins doesn't have a single indented code.).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/

Comment: Patrick Artner, yes i saw it, but in my case I have to take into account the number of coins I have, the algorithm that is given in this link just calculates the optimal number of coins

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
if sub_res +1 <= how[j] :
```

Here you check that you don't use more coins that `how[j]` has, but in fact these `sub_res + 1` coins can have different values, not just `coins[j]` value. Minimal example:

```
coins = [1, 2]
howmanycoins = [1, 1]
m = len(coins)
V = 3
```

won't work, because you will need 2 coins obviously, but `2 > how[0]` and `2 > how[1]`, but in this case you use 1 coin of each value.

For solving your issue you should save all used coins for each value and change your algorithm to brute force.